# Can the following operation be performed in a single query without using explicit Maps or nesting Queries?

Tags: query

Is there a way to include the function `StringPosition["e"]` inside the `Query` in the following:

```
query=Query[
    Histogram[Flatten@#]&,
    All,
    First
]@*StringPosition["e"]
```

There are three functions in use here `Histogram[Flatten@#]&`, `First` and `StringPosition["e"]`.

Is there a way to rewrite the `query` in such a way that when compiled it produces the following:

```
Normal[query]
```

> ```
> StringPosition["e"]/*Map[Map[First]]/*(Histogram[Flatten[#1]]&)
> ```

I tried rewriting it like as follows:

```
query=Query[
    StringPosition["e"]/*(Histogram[Flatten@#]&),
    All,
    First
]
```

But it doesn't compile to the required form:

```
Normal[query]
```

> ```
> Map[Map[First]]/*StringPosition["e"]/*(Histogram[Flatten[#1]]&)
> ```

Comment: Could you please elaborate on why a nested query is unacceptable?  A subquery would be the canonical way to delay the `All` and `First` descending operators so that we get the desired compiled form:  `Normal @ Query[StringPosition["e"]/*Query[Histogram[Flatten@#]&,All,First]]`.

Comment: First query was submitted as an answer to the Day 7 challenge [here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1935390).